# GitHub Actions error when using serilog.json configuration file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, github-actions, serilog

GitHub Actions and serilog.json

I'm trying to set up GitHub Actions for my .NET core project. I'm getting errors in the unit testing phase as well. When I run everything locally, ie run the **dotnet test** command, all the tests run. However, when I do a git push, my 2 tests fail.
Here is the error message:

```
Error Message:
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException : The configuration file 'AnimeViewedDiary.Infrastructure\serilog.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/home/runner/work/animeViewedDiary/animeViewedDiary/src/AnimeViewedDiary.Infrastructure\serilog.json'.
  Stack Trace:
     at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
```

In my project I use serilog.json file located at src/AnimeViewDiary.Infrastucture/serilog.json. It is configured in the UnitOfWorkRepository file. The tests themselves are located under the path tests/AnimeViewDiary.Data.UnitTests/... The following test is not executed:

```
[Fact]
    public void SaveChanges_SuccessSaveChanges_SaveChanges()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<DiaryApplicationDbContext> mockApplicationDbContext =
            UnitOfWorkConfiguration.CreateMockApplicationDbContext();
        Mock<DiaryIdentityDbContext> mockIdentityDbContext =
            UnitOfWorkConfiguration.CreateMockIdentityDbContext();

        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(mockIdentityDbContext.Object,
            mockApplicationDbContext.Object);

        // Act
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

        // Assert
        mockApplicationDbContext.Verify(options => options.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
        mockIdentityDbContext.Verify(options => options.SaveChanges(), Times.Once);
    }
```

Here is the UnitOfWork file itself, located at the path src/AnimeViewDiary.Data/Repositories/Based/UnitOfWork.cs:

```
public UnitOfWork(DiaryIdentityDbContext identityDbContext, DiaryApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        string currentDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Name;
        
        const string projectName = "AnimeViewedDiary.Infrastructure";
        const string projectApiName = "AnimeViewedDiary.WebAPI";
        const string serilogFileName = "serilog.json";
        const string srcDirectoryName = "src";
        
        string srcFolderPath;
        
        if (currentDirectory == projectApiName)
            srcFolderPath = Directory.GetParent(currentDirectory)?.Parent?.ToString()!;
        else
        {
            string rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDirectory).Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent?.Parent
                ?.ToString()!;
            srcFolderPath = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, srcDirectoryName);
        }
        
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(srcFolderPath, projectName) + "\\";
        string pathToFile = fullPath + serilogFileName;
        
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile(pathToFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .Build();
        
        ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        _identityDbContext = identityDbContext;
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        UserRepository = new UserRepository(_identityDbContext, logger);
    }
```

I don't really understand what it can be connected with. I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

GHW:

```
name: Build and Testing .NET AnimeViewedDiary Project

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "*"
      - "*/*"
      - "**"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "*"
      - "*/*"
      - "**"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: ["7.0.x"]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup .NET Core SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
          
      - name: Restore/Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build project
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
        
      - name: Unit tests
        run: dotnet test
```

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow in your question.

Comment: @Azeem Attached

Comment: On your local setup, do you have Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: After checkout, you need to verify if `/home/runner/work/animeViewedDiary/animeViewedDiary/src/AnimeViewedDiary.Infrastructure\serilog.json` file path is correct. You can run `ls -l /home/runner/work/animeViewedDiary/animeViewedDiary/src/AnimeViewedDiary.Infrastructure\serilog.json` in a separate step after checkout to verify this.

Comment: @Azeem Everything works, I made a stupid mistake in the code itself. I used an incorrect slash before the file name serilog.json) Thanks